# Haskell warning

Tags: haskell, warnings

I have written the code (I'm new to haskell, very new) and can't solve the warning.

problem:

```
funk ::  Num a => a -> a
funk a = a + 10 
main :: IO()
main = print (funk 10 )
```

***Warning:***

```
Warnings: 1

  /home/anmnv/Desktop/qqq.hs: line 4, column 8:
    Warning: • Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘Integer’
    (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print’ at qqq.hs:4:8-23
    (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘funk’ at qqq.hs:4:15-21
• In the expression: print (funk 10)
  In an equation for ‘main’: main = print (funk 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply says that you did not specify the type for `10`. It can strictly speaking by any type that is an member of the [**`Num`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num), but the compiler uses defaulting rules, and thus picks an [**`Integer`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integer).

You can give Haskell a type constraint to determine the type of `10`, for example:

```
funk :: Num a => a -> a
funk = (+ 10)

main :: IO ()
main = print (funk (10 :: Integer))
```